# Get entries based on custom field lightswitch in custom plugin in Craft 2

Tags: plugin-development, craft2

I am trying to get the entries in my custom plugin template ( CP )

Each entry has a lightswitch I want to fetch only those where lightswitch is enabled.

In controller file:

```PHP
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section('articles');
$criteria->relatedTo(array(
    'field' => 'lightswitchFieldHandle'
));
$criteria->limit = 20;
$products['entries'] = $criteria->find();
$this->renderTemplate('sponsoredentries/_index', $products);
```

But I am getting 20 entries (as per limit but not as per field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of your Lightswitch field directly instead of using the `relatedTo` parameter

```PHP
$criteria->lightswitchFieldHandle = '1';
```

Comment: ok will try as you suggest, but can you please help to understand that when we use `relatedTo` and when we use the way you suggested.Thank You.

Comment: the `relatedTo` parameter is only used when you want to filter for related elements. So when you have `users`, `entries`, `categories` or `assets` fields. For example when you want to display only entries with a certain category. You can learn more about that here https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/relations.html

Comment: Is this applied same when we fetch in fronted template.

Comment: There is no difference between Twig and PHP logic when it comes to Objects

Comment: You mean this way : 

https://gist.github.com/maddyBoy/db14ef067033b78837fc4e6fc351c1d2

Comment: Ah you mean "how is it applied" not "if it is applied" yeah that should be correct

Comment: Its working fine, i got only those entries where lightswitchFieldHandle = 1,
`Thank you`

Comment: Can you please see this issue of mine. 
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29673/update-a-custom-field-lightswitchfieldhandle-in-custom-plugin-controller-folde