# Update a lightswitch field in Craft CMS 2

Tags: controller, craft2, saveentry

How can I edit a lightswitch field in an entries field layout via PHP? This is my current approach

```PHP
public function actionSponsoredEntriesPriority() {
    $this->requireAdmin();
    $this->requireAjaxRequest();
    $success = false;
    $message = Craft::t('Any message from controller');

    $newPriority = craft()->request->getPost('newPriority');
    $entryId = craft()->request->getPost('entryId');

    $entries = craft()->entries;

    $entry = $entries->getEntryById($entryId);

    if ($entry != null) {
        $entry->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
            'lightswitchFieldHandle' => 1
        ));

        $success = $entries->saveEntry($entry);
        $success == true;
    } else {
        //return null;
        $success = false;
    }
}
```

But since there are other required fields that are currently empty for this entry I receive the following response

> message: {featureImage: ["Feature Image cannot be blank."], hero: ["Header cannot be blank."]}

I tried to resave the required fields still stuck at matrix field.
Here is code [Reset required field](https://gist.github.com/maddyBoy/feed5b2c2daa97398d5ac93d63418fc5)

> Error : Correct the errors listed above.

Do i need to update the required field as well or there is a way to bypass while updating a field ?

> Update : Solution as suggested in answer [Update field directly ]

```
public function actionSponsoredEntriesPriority() {
        // $this->requireAdmin();
        // $this->requireAjaxRequest();
        $newPriority = craft()->request->getPost('newPriority');
        $entryId = craft()->request->getPost('entryId');
        $success = false;
        $message = Craft::t('Any message from controller');

        // entries object
        $entries = craft()->entries;
        // entries  by id ( $entryId passed by js )
        $entry = $entries->getEntryById($entryId);

        if ($entry != null) {
                $command = craft()->db->createCommand();
                $success = $command->update(
                    'content', // table name
                    array(
                    'field_lightswitchFieldHandle' => 1,
                    'field_sponsoredEntriesPriority' => $newPriority
                    ), // fields
                    'elementId=:id',
                    array(':id'=> $entryId)
                    );
                $message = Craft::t('Priority saved');
                $success == true;
            } else {
            //return null;
            $success = false;
        }
        // send response true/false with message
       if($success == true){
           $this->returnJson(
            array(
                'success' => $success,
                'message' => $message
            ));
       }else{
           $this->returnJson(
            array(
                'success' => $success,
                'message' => $entry->getErrors()
            ));
       }
    }
```

Comment: As soon as an Element has content and is enabled it will be validated, in Craft 2 there is no "easy and fast" way to prevent it. You could either recreate the `EntriesService` and include the parameter `$success = craft()->elements->saveElement($entry, false);` or if you only want to edit the single field create a query and set it directly in your content column

Comment: if i use direct query is there any dependency on any another table while updating one field value.

Comment: No, the `dateUpdated` value in your entry won't be updated but if that's no problem there are no other dependencies. Well and certain events won't be fired such as `afterSave` but if you don't need them there are no disadvantages

Comment: Ok thank you, will try to update directly, In craft 3 is this solved ?

Comment: Yes Craft 3 handles everything much better. If you can I would suggest you to update for countless reasons. The main one is the switch from Yii to Yii2. Yii is really old

Comment: Actually we are doing modification in an existing project, but alongside we are working on version 3 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only one single field and you want to bypass all Craft validations for required fields you can change the value directly in your database using [Yii commands](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#building-data-manipulation-queries) and the `update` function

```PHP
function update($table, $columns, $conditions='', $params=array())
```

```PHP
$command = craft()->db->createCommand();
$command->update('craft_content', 
    array(
        'field_yourLightSwitchField' => 1,
    ), 
    'elementId=:id', array(':id'=>1)
);
```

If you have a multilocale setup you need to include the condition for the correct locale as well

Comment: ii think we dont need to add `craft_` as YII did this for us.